# ModuleNotFoundError in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: package pyacoustid appear in pip-list but cannot import]

I'm trying to use pyacoustid and install it using pip.

But when I run code on vscode terminal or cmd, although package pyacoustid appears in pip list it is still not found when import in python code.

I'm using python version 3.8.5 and also change python interpreter in vscode to this version.

I don't know what's wrong with my computer or my python interpreter.

Hope anyone can help me.

Kind regards.

Comment: `pip --version` and `python --version` please. Your pip is probably not the one connected to your python version. To fix this, use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`

Comment: `pip 22.0.4 from c:\users\hieupnd\appdata\local\programs\pythoncodingpack\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

`Python 3.8.5`

I install and use it in the same python interpreter in vs code

Comment: i used python -m pip install pyacoustid but got the same result

Comment: When you use the code "pip install pyacoustid", what is the content displayed on the terminal? @Hiếu Phan